# Extand main APFS partition on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, mojave, apfs

As it can be seen from the screenshot below my `APPLE SSD` is of size 500GBs, but my `Apple_APFS Container disk1` is of size 450GBs. There was a `Container disk 2` of size 50GBs before but I successfully removed it using:

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s4
```

I tried resizing the main APFS cotnainer with the following command:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a
>   gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small,
>   which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the
>   beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map
>   usable space

Following some screenshots displaying the current state of the sysetm:

```
 diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         449.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Apple_KernelCoreDump                         655.4 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +449.3 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            362.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 55.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output, from the commands below, should show that `disk0s3` starts at an offset that is sufficiently close to the end of `disk0s2` to produce the error message you posted.

```
diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e "Disk Size"
diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Offset -e "Disk Size"
```

Or, in other words:

```
(Offset of disk0s2) + (Size of disk0s2) - (Offset of disk0s3) = (Small enough size to cause message)
```

You do not need the `Apple_KernelCoreDump` partition. You can remove this partition be entering the command below.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" none disk0s3
```

Next, you can reenter the command you posted in your question to reclaim the free space.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I just tried the aforementioned commands and everything worked like a charm! :)